# How I get the parameter value in my twig extension class of symfony2

Tags: symfony

I need to get a parameter value in my following twig extension class

```
namespace xxxx\WebBundle\Twig;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension

{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('affliate', array($this, 'urlFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function urlFilter($url,$aff)
    {
        $separator = "?";
        if (strpos($url,"?")!=false) {
            $separator = "&";
        }
        $parse = parse_url($url);
        //echo $parse['host'];

        $app_url = $url.$separator.'tag='.$aff;

        return $app_url;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'wishbot_extension';
    }
}
```

In controller we can use like this $this->container->getParameter('contact_email');
But I need the value in twig extension class.

Comment: did my answer help you resolve your question or is anything unclear? if yes please comment , otherwise please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the parameters as arguments into your twig extensions's constructor like this:

**config.yml**

```
services:
    twig.extension.your_extension:
        class: Vendor\YourBundle\Twig\Extension\YourExtension
        arguments: [ %parameter1%, %parameter2% ]         
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**YourExtension.php**

```
protected $parameter1;
protected $parameter1;

public function __construct($parameter1, $parameter2)
{
    $this->parameter1 = $parameter1;
    $this->parameter2 = $parameter2;
}

// ....

public function urlFilter($url,$aff)
{
     // access the parameters using $this->parameter1
}
```